# Simple angular app, the html does not recognise the app

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to do my first angular.js app following this presentation : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnXO-i7944M

My code are

html:

```
<!doctyme html>
<html ng-app="gfaApp">
<head>
    <script src="./angular.js">
    </script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.4/angular-resource.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.4/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./angular.js">
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="statsController">
    <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <hr>
    <h1>Hello {{yourName}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and js

```
var app = angular.module('gfaApp', []);
app.controller('statsController', function($scope){
    $scope.seances = [
        {"id":1 , "title":"seance1 ,multi-acces", "stats":150},
        {"id":2 , "title":"seance 2  ,etre administrateur", "stats":550},
        {"id":3 , "title":"seance3, comment gérer sa vie", "stats":10},
        {"id":4 , "title":"derniere seance , comment réussir son breakfast", "stats":15150}
        ];
    $scope.yourName = "";
        });
```

When I don't do `<html ng-app="gfaApp">` but simply `<html ng-app >` everything is fine.

Did I do something wrong with my code?

Thanks a lot

Comment: can you post what is the error you are getting in the console

Comment: You are referencing `angular.js` script twice in your markup

Comment: the order of referencing the angular files is also important. make sure you reference the angular.js files first followed by your script file references

Comment: What is your js file called?

Answer (score 0):

I recreated this in a JSBin [here](http://jsbin.com/aDuJIku/282/edit?html,js,output) and it works fine- my guess is the problem has something to do with the way you are referring to the angular.js file, ie with :

```
<script src="./angular.js">
```

Try replacing that with

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>
```

instead.

EDIT: Ah, and as someone pointed out above, referencing the angular.js file twice can't be helping matters..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my dummy question above, I was just a little bit lost with my code.

The second load of script file was normally for another js file (the one with my controller)

Now it works,

Sorry for losing your time

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('statsController', function($scope){
    $scope.seances = [
        {"id":1 , "title":"seance1 ,multi-acces", "stats":150},
        {"id":2 , "title":"seance 2  ,etre administrateur", "stats":550},
        {"id":3 , "title":"seance3, comment gérer sa vie", "stats":10},
        {"id":4 , "title":"derniere seance , comment réussir son breakfast", "stats":15150}
        ];
    $scope.yourName = "";
        });
```

and

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

Comment: Explain what changes were made and why they were made. You have just pasted code without any explanation.

Comment: Simply renaming the module will not change a thing

Comment: @TimCastelijns too little info about errors in console. How do i know maybe he forget include js with app and controller in scripts of index.html?

Comment: @TimCastelijns but he wrote that after use ng-app without name reference code works fine. Before he don`t show errors that is a divination

Comment: If you don't know those details, how can you answer his question?

Comment: @TimCastelijns i can not get a details from comments of question. I do  not understand that system with 50 rep that limits me with getting info about question from author

Comment: Ah yes I understand that :-) been there myself